# Kobo App: Metadata_username value to send to MainMenuActivity.xml

Tags: android-studio, kobo, kobotoolbox

I just want to ask a question because I am customizing the Kobo app on my android device.

I just want to ask how I can get the metada_username value to be displayed in my MainMenuActivity.xml after I scan the QR code.

PS: the QR code is already customized and has a metada_username included. Also in my project settings, it is displaying the metadata_username from the QR in the Form Metadata.

Please somebody help me!! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to get the metadata_username value from a QR code that contains a URL like this:

```
https://example.com/login?metadata_username=john&metadata_password=1234
```

You can use the **ZXing library** to scan the QR code and get the raw data as a string:

```
https://example.com/login?metadata_username=john&metadata_password=1234
```

Then you can use a URL parser library or method to parse the URL and get the query parameters as a map:

```
{metadata_username: john, metadata_password: 1234}
```

Finally, you can access the metadata_username value from the map by using its key:

```
String metadata_username = map.get ("metadata_username");
```

To display the metadata_username value in your `MainMenuActivity.xml`, you can use a `TextView` element and set its text attribute to the metadata_username value:

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/metadata_username_text"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@{metadata_username}" />
```

Comment: actually, the Kobo app itself has a decoder for the QR itself because the QR is in JSON format, encrypted with base64, and then compress it using zlib. I just can't figure out how I can use it to display also on my Main Menu.